# best way implement filtering using mybatis

Tags: mybatis

I've got a table with some fields and some search form for that table. 
I want to add ability to filter items in the table using this form. 
To implement this I want to do select from the table with parameters, acquired from the search form.

But the problem is **what is the best way to implement it using MyBatis and its XML mapper?**

I don't like my solution because if there up to 10 parameters - query will be huge...

```
<select id="getFilteredDevelopers" parameterType="map" resultMap="DeveloperResult">
    select
        developer_id,
        private_information
    from pmc.developer
    <choose>
        <when test="filterId != null and filterPrivateInformation == null">
            where developer_id like #{filterId}
        </when>
        <when test="filterId != null and filterPrivateInformation != null">
            where developer_id like #{filterId} and private_information like #{filterPrivateInformation}
        </when>
        <when test="filterId == null and filterPrivateInformation != null">
            where private_information like #{filterPrivateInformation}
        </when>
    </choose>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well...I was not able to find something better than

```
<select id="getFilteredProjects" resultMap="ProjectResult" parameterType="map">
    select
        project_id,
        project_name,
        project_owner
    from pmc.project
    where TRUE
    <choose>
        <when test="projectId != null">
            and project_id like #{projectId}
        </when>
        <when test="projectName != null">
            and project_name like #{projectName}
        </when>
        <when test="projectOwner != null">
            and project_owner like #{projectOwner}
        </when>
    </choose>
</select>
```

Though it's better than before anyway.

Comment: Just a small change maybe but, you may substitute the "where TRUE" part with "<where>" and then close the tag after </choose>.